# Using variables established from another Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Subs:  'PNL_Monthly_Actuals_Main' & 'PNL_Monthly_Actuals1'.  The fname string used in the "Main" sub is relevant for the second sub "Actuals1".  The Main sub opens a PNL workbook based on the fname entered in the input box and then also chooses a budget workbook that is open to execute the "PNL_Monthly_Actuals1" subroutine.  In the "...Actuals1" subroutine, I repeated the input box to enter the fname so I can use it for a SUMPRODUCT formula and to set a workbook dimension.  How can I avoid repeating the input box and reference the fname from the "...Main" sub?

```
Sub PNL_Monthly_Actuals_Main()

 Dim fpath As String
 Dim fname As String

 fpath = "I:\Finance & Accounting\Finance\Budget 2015\Supporting Files\PNL's"
 **fname = InputBox("Enter PNL File Name")**

 Set PNLWb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath & "\" & fname & ".xlsx")


Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
If Left(wb.Name, 6) = "Budget" Then
YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on " & wb.Name & "?", vbYesNo, "Where to run marco?")
If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then
wb.Activate
With wb
For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
If Left(sheet.Name, 2) = "By" Then
YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on worksheet " & sheet.Name & "?", vbYesNo, "Where to run marco?")
If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then
sheet.Activate
If sheet.Name = "By SubMarket" Then
'Put sub name here
Call PNL_Monthly_Actuals1
Else
Call PNL_Monthly_Actuals2
End If

End If
End If
Next sheet
End With
End If
End If
Next wb

PNLWb.Close

End Sub

Sub PNL_Monthly_Actuals1()
   'Define Budget Template Workbook
    'Define the BySubMarket tab in the Budget Template Workbook
    'Define the PNL workbook that is being evaluated
    'Define the file path where the PNL reports are stored
    'Input box to manually enter file name to open

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim BudWkb As Workbook
    Dim Wk2 As Worksheet
    Dim PNLWkb As Workbook
    Dim fpath As String
    Dim fname As String

    Set BudWkb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Wk2 = ActiveSheet

    fname = InputBox("Enter PNL File Name")

    Set PNLWkb = Workbooks(fname)




    With PNLWkb

        Dim Wk1 As Worksheet
        Set Wk1 = PNLWkb.Sheets("det")

        With Wk1

        Dim FRow As Long
        Dim lRow As Long
        Dim SbMktCol As Long
        Dim ExpCol As Long

        Dim Expense As String
        Expense = InputBox("Enter Expense GL")


    'to locate begining and ending row of data on PNL report
    'Identifies the column where the SubMarket names are located for lookup purposes
    'Defines the expense GL column to lookup based on the inputbox above
    FRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(2, 0).row
    lRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", LookAt:=xlPart).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).row
    SbMktCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Submarket", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    ExpCol = Wk1.Cells.Find(Expense, LookAt:=xlPart).Column

    'Defines the Range of the Sub-Market Names
    Dim SbMktRg As Range
    Set SbMktRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, SbMktCol), Wk1.Cells(lRow, SbMktCol))

    'Defines the exact range of the expense column being analyzed
    Dim ExpRg As Range
    Set ExpRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, ExpCol), Wk1.Cells(lRow, ExpCol))

        End With
    End With






    With BudWkb
        With Wk2
            Dim Period As String

            Period = InputBox("Enter MM/D/YYYY of Period for Oct-Dec or Enter M/D/YYYY for periods prior to Oct")
            Dim ActualCol As Long
            ActualCol = Wk2.Cells.Find(Period, LookAt:=xlPart).Offset(0, 1).Column

            Dim sRow As Long
            Dim SubCol As Long
            Dim eRow As Long


            sRow = Wk2.Cells.Find("Sub-Market", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).row
            SubCol = Wk2.Cells.Find("Sub-Market", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
            eRow = Wk2.Range(Wk2.Cells(sRow, SubCol), Wk2.Cells(rows.Count, SubCol)).Find("TOTAL", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(-1, 0).row

            Dim ActualRg As Range
            Set ActualRg = Wk2.Range(Wk2.Cells(sRow, ActualCol), Wk2.Cells(eRow, ActualCol))


            With ActualRg
                .Formula = "=-SUMPRODUCT(--('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & SbMktRg.Address & "=C4),'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & ExpRg.Address & ")"
                .Value = .Value
            End With


            Dim pLRow As Long
            pLRow = Wk2.Cells.Find("P/L Sub-Markets Total", LookAt:=xlWhole).row

            With Wk2.Cells(pLRow, ActualCol)
            .Formula = "=-SUMPRODUCT(--('[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & SbMktRg.Address & "<>""""),'[" & fname & ".xlsx]det'!" & ExpRg.Address & ")"

            End With
        End With
    End With







    'optional:
    'ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="YYYYMMDD.xls"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Add ```fname``` as parameter to ```Sub PNL_Monthly_Actuals1(fname As String)```. In ```Main``` just use ```Call PNL_Monthly_Actuals1 (fname)```.

Comment: Thanks @Dee for teaching me something new.  I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the variable globally. Example:

```
Dim myVar As String '<-- globally declared, out of any specific sub-function

Sub myMacro1()
    myVar = "ciao"
    myMacro2
End Sub

Sub myMacro2()
    MsgBox myVar '<-- this was defined in myMacro1, but it's used in myMacro2
End Sub
```

In your specific case, just take out

```
Dim fname As String
```

from the Sub and put it outside of it. The macro Actuals1 will remember this.

Alternatively, pass it as a parameter, which means rewrite the macro declaration:

```
Sub PNL_Actuals1(ByVal fname As String)

End Sub
```

and then call the macro with the parameter:

```
Call PNL_Actuals1(fname)
```

or even better

```
PNL_Actuals1 fname
```

Comment: Thanks Matteo for an alternative route.  Like I commented on the other response, I just learned something new and will use both approaches on other projects I build.